# Error, int given when trying to map a Doctrine query result to a DTO

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dto

I have this configuration:

Agent entity class:

```
/**
 * Agent
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="agent")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AgentRepository")
 */
class Agent
{
  ...
```

Agent DTO:

```
class AgentDTO
{

    public function __construct(Agent $agent)
    {
      ...
```

Agent repository:

```
public function findAgentByField(string $field)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('NEW App\DTO\AgentDTO(a)')
        ->from('App:Agent', 'a')
        ->where('a.field= :field')
        ->setParameter('field', $field)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This throws the following error.

> Argument 1 passed to App\DTO\AgentDTO::__construct() must be an
>   instance of App\Entity\Agent, int given

I have put this `$arg_list = func_get_args();` into the constructor of `AgentDTO` and I noticed there is a single parameter which is the identifier of the entity. Why isn't it an instance of `Agent`?

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax reads to me, as if that syntax expects the *fields* of the entity. possibly `a` is interpreted as `a.id`? the last sentence of that section says "Note that you can only pass scalar expressions to the constructor.", so apparently the entity a is "scalarized" to its id.

Comment: @Jakumi indeed. I suppose there is no possible way to pass the full entity then?

Comment: I assume it's not possible, but the obvious fallback is to use the query result to create the DTOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation clearly states:

> Note that you can only pass scalar expressions to the constructor.

But still, there is another possible way to map your result to DTO - by providing custom [hydration mode](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes):

In the end of the query specify a hydrator name:

```
...
->getQuery()
->getResult('AgentHydrator');
```

Then, in your config file under `orm` property specify hydrator mappings (Symfony [docs link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#shortened-configuration-syntax)):

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    ...
    hydrators:
      AgentHydrator: My\Bundle\Hydrators\Agent\AgentHydrator
```

And finally specify the custom hydrator:

```
class AgentHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function hydrateAllData()
    {
        $result = [];

        while ($data = $this->_stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $result[] = new AgentDTO($data);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```